# two column layout with same proportions of content area as window is larger then content area

Tags: html, css, layout

Sorry for the awkward working.

The content area lets say is 1000px, I want the left column to be 25% and the right to be 75%, yet as the window is wider then 1000px, I want the columns to keep the same proportions, yet have their backgrnd-color bleed off to teir corresponding sides. Here are a couple of images to  try and help illustrate the point:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvWrp.jpg

Here the image is 25% left column and 75% right column

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvWrp.jpg#1

Here, the content area is the same as above, yet with the left column being 25%% of the left column and 75% of the right, yet there backnd colors, extend to the edge while keeping that internal proportion.

I know there is a way to do this via js, just wandering if there is a way to do it with just css/html

also, the black area would have an image that covers all of the black area.

Thanks for any help!

EDIT: ended up using calc() as it's been supported for a bit

Answer (score 0):

There are probably several ways to do what you're asking. Here's a codepen.io pen showing one way: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zxYgRp

And I've copied the code here:

### HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
   <nav></nav>
   <div id="main"></div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #ff0000; /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #ff0000 0%, #ff0000 50%, #cccccc 51%, #cccccc 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,#ff0000), color-stop(50%,#ff0000), color-stop(51%,#cccccc), color-stop(100%,#cccccc)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #ff0000 0%,#ff0000 50%,#cccccc 51%,#cccccc 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #ff0000 0%,#ff0000 50%,#cccccc 51%,#cccccc 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #ff0000 0%,#ff0000 50%,#cccccc 51%,#cccccc 100%); /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #ff0000 0%,#ff0000 50%,#cccccc 51%,#cccccc 100%); /* W3C */

}

#wrapper { 
  max-width: 40em;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}

nav { 
  background: #f00;
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#main { 
  background: #ccc; 
  min-height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Basically, we're creating a wrapper with a maximum width, then adding a background gradient that goes from the nav color to the main right column color right in the middle. I used this CSS gradient generator: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

I added borders around the nav (as left sidebar) and main content area so you can see where they end and where the background color begins.

Comment: Thanks, this definitely works, but I guess I'm looking for a "true" way to carry the color to the edges as there will be a background image that extends the width of the black/gray area.

Comment: I know there is a way to do this via js, just wandering if there is a way to do it with just css/html

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding another answer to show how to do it a different way based on OP's clarification. You'll notice I use background images.

Here is the code pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PwoMxw

### HTML

```
<div id="sidebar">
  <nav></nav>
</div>
<div id="main">
  <div id="main-inner"></div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
body { margin: 0; padding: 0;}

#sidebar {
    width: 25%;
   background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/xDe7IaC.jpg);
    position: fixed;
    min-height: 100%;
}

nav {
   max-width: 100%;
   width: 16em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

#main {
  width: 75%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(http://i.imgur.com/OYjJ4yS.jpg);
}

#main-inner {
  width: 48em;
  max-width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

There is liberal use of position: absolute here and the proportions would have to be refined, but this is one way to accomplish the goal.

Comment: ya that's as far as I've gotten, but it's not centered.